# Select items in table A that didn't have any new records in table B

Tags: mysql

Within `table B` I have a column `created_at`.

I want to select all rows from `table A` that didn't have a new row created within `table B` in the last 1-2 minutes from the last entry.

If I run query on the table below at 18:01:01, the result should only include tableA_id with ID 1.

```
Table B
id, tableA_id createdAt
1, 1, 18:00:00
2, 1, 17:59:00
3, 2, 17:59:00
4, 3, 18:01:00
```

My current query looks similar to the query below:

```
SELECT tableA.*
FROM tableA
INNER JOIN tableB ON tableB.tableA_id = tableA.id
WHERE tableB.created_at NOT BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
    AND tableB.created_at BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE AND NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MINUTE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `missing` record, you cannot use `INNER JOIN` because this will output only existing record.

I'm not sure which interval you want.  Try this for no record from 1 minute in past to now.

```
SELECT tableA.*
FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableB.tableA_id = tableA.id
                AND tableB.createdAt between now() interval -1 minute and now()
where tableB.tableA_id is null;
```

Comment: I also want to exclude records that didn't have new records for over 2 minutes. I am writing an alert script that meant to be run once a minute. Also, we should not be sending alerts more than once. If nothing new was added for more then a minute -> alert is sent, once.

Comment: Is my query is working?  Replace `-1 minute` by `-2 minute`.  It should output entries from `table_A` where no matching entries in `table_B` within last 2 minutes.

Comment: Your query is working to an extend. Had to add an extra where condition to filter by `createdAt >= interval -2 minute`. I didn't have a need for `tableB.tableA_id is null either`